# C# Sorting listbox items by date

Tags: c#

i've some kind of txt which includes that kind of strings.

```
 "xxxx || Expire = 2020-10-17:23-25-51";
  "xxxx || Expire = 2020-09-17:23-25-51" ;
```

there are many lines in txt with these strings (line by line)
I'm able to sorting these with getting "2020-10-17" part but i'm not able to sort whole line. I mean i can get characters after Expire = "**2020-10-17**"  but I want to sort each row among themselves.

```
locChar = AllIndexesOf(str, "Expire = ");
str = str.Substring(locChar[0], 10);
lstStr.Add(str);
..
   var Sortlist = lstStr.OrderByDescending(x =>
            {
                DateTime dt;
                DateTime.TryParse(x, out dt);
                return dt;
            }).ToList() ;
```

output :

```
2020-07-21
2020-07-07
2020-06-28
```

i want to get output like this

```
"xxxx || Expire = 2020-07-21"
"xxxx || Expire = 2020-07-07"
```

Comment: consider parsing that into a strongly typed model intead of the string.

Comment: A (Winforms) ListBox can take a collection of *objects* as a *DataSource* such that you can simply sort that source by the **date** in the class.  Easy-peasy

Comment: You need to move the `locChar = AllIndexesOf(str, "Expire = ");
str = str.Substring(locChar[0], 10);` into the sort key selector and sort the original data. See duplicate. There are of course even better ways to approach your problem, but the duplicates address your question directly and include alternatives you may prefer.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would suggest is fixing the input line format:

- Do not use `:` to separate date and time, since it is mostly used as a separator between hour, minute and second parts.
- Be consistent with whitespaces.
- Double quotes and semicolon does not seem needed.

Inputs you provided does not look as good test cases. So, I used below as one:

```
"1 || Expire = 2020-10-17 23:25:51";
"2 || Expire = 2020-09-16 23:25:51";
"3 || Expire = 2020-09-10 23:25:51";
```

And added `using System.Linq`, then ran below code:

```
var inputLines = input.Split(new char[]{ '\n' });
var inputLineGroups = inputLines.Select(x => x.Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
var sortedLineGroups = inputLineGroups.OrderBy(y => y[1]);
var sortedFullLines = sortedLineGroups.Select(z => z[0] + "||" + z[1]);
    
foreach(var line in sortedFullLines){
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
"3 || Expire = 2020-09-10 23:25:51";
"2 || Expire = 2020-09-16 23:25:51";
"1 || Expire = 2020-10-17 23:25:51";
```

If you want to remove the hours, a slight change will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

this would sort a list of strings by the logic you posted:

```
  List<string> lstStr = new List<string>() { "xxxx || Expire = 2020-07-21:23-25-51" ,
                                                       "xxxx || Expire = 2020-06-28:23-25-51" ,
                                                       "xxxx || Expire = 2020-07-07:23-25-51" ,
                                                       "xxxx || Expire = 2020-10-17:23-25-51" ,
                                                       "xxxx || Expire = 2020-09-17:23-25-51" };
  lstStr = lstStr.Select(x => x.Split(':')[0]).ToList();
  lstStr.Sort((str1, str2) =>
  {
      DateTime dt1;
      DateTime.TryParse(str1.Substring(str1.IndexOf("Expire = ") + 9, 10), out dt1); 

      DateTime dt2;
      DateTime.TryParse(str2.Substring(str2.IndexOf("Expire = ") + 9, 10), out dt2);
      return dt1.CompareTo(dt2);
  });

  lstStr.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

you said you have a listbox so if you want it to be sorted, you could inheret from listbox and override the sort method in it, that way you can just set `listBox.Sorted = true`
(it wouldn't modify the string, but it would keep it sorted)

```
    public class SortedListbox : ListBox
    {
        public SortedListbox() : base()
        {
        }

        protected override void Sort()
        {
            if (Items.Count > 1)
            {
                object dataSource = null;
                if (this.DataSource != null)
                {
                    dataSource = this.DataSource;
                    this.DataSource = null;
                }

                bool swapped;
                do
                {
                    int counter = Items.Count - 1;
                    swapped = false;

                    while (counter > 0)
                    {
                        DateTime dt1;
                        DateTime.TryParse(Items[counter].ToString().Substring(Items[counter].ToString().IndexOf("Expire = ") + 9, 10), out dt1);

                        DateTime dt2;
                        DateTime.TryParse(Items[counter - 1].ToString().Substring(Items[counter - 1].ToString().IndexOf("Expire = ") + 9, 10), out dt2);
                        
                        if (dt1 < dt2)
                        {
                            object temp = Items[counter];
                            Items[counter] = Items[counter - 1];
                            Items[counter - 1] = temp;
                            swapped = true;
                        }

                        counter -= 1;
                    }
                }
                while ((swapped == true));
                
                if (dataSource != null)
                {
                    this.DataSource = dataSource;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```